# Type hints with Memoization through decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators, type-hinting

I have implemented memoization through a function decorator like this:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.foo = 1337

class Memoize:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
        self.memo = {}
    def __call__(self, *args):
        if not args in self.memo:
            self.memo[args] = self.f(*args)
        return self.memo[args]

@Memoize
def get_file(file_path: str) -> A:
    return A(file_path)

a = get_file("bar.txt").foo
```

The code works fine but VSCode can't resolve the type of a anymore.

If I explicitly give the return type in the call function, it works as expected, i.e. just changing this line in Memoize:

```py
    def __call__(self, *args) -> A:
```

Of course, then the Memoize class is not general anymore. Is there a way to set the type hint to whatever the output of f is?

Comment: Maybe just use the built-in `functools.cache` decorator; it's bound to be correctly typed.

Comment: If you're interested in return type only, something like [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=f118080b4dd1604e4c1776000083e666) should work (please prefer `args not in self.memo` for readability - `not args in self.memo` is a bit weird to read).

Comment: Both of these solutions work, thank you